# What is a word to describe someone who likes being together with others but not necessarily sociable or a "social butterfly"?

Tags: single-word-requests

To describe someone who always likes being in a group and doing everything together with people (i.e. too shy to do things alone) but not necessarily outgoing or sociable, or as they call "a social butterfly"?

example: I am a _______ / I am very ______

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Im sorry I'm not really looking to use it in a sentence, I just need one word. to fill in an application. It should be a noun or adjective.

Comment: Have you tired, "group-oriented"

Comment: I think that works! Thank you so much !

Comment: At the duplicate I've linked to (and others), 'gregarious' is the prototypical answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Gregarious people are outgoing and interested in meeting new people. The question specifically mentions this is not what they are looking for.  I'm tired of these threads being closed because people misread the very clear questions.

Comment: I am an insecure wallflower.

Comment: @GArthurBrown I'm tired of having to explain myself. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gregarious)'s first definition for 'gregarious' is 'tending to associate with others of one's kind' which fits to a tee. Yes, there are other sub-senses, but that does not disqualify this one. //  The question I've linked to as a duplicate contains 'What do you call a person who likes to connect to new people', and this present thread  will almost certainly not generate valid new answers. 'Group-oriented' of course defaults to 'targeted at / designed for groups' ... although if you could ...

Comment: provide an appropriate secondary definition from a dictionary meaning 'liking to be around other people without necessarily being sociable', that _would_ be a valid answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Look at the title of the question you link to.

Comment: @GArthurBrown '... likes ... being in a group and doing everything together with people' must overlap to a fair extent with 'likes to chat/connect to new people'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not necessarily. This is is looking for a more specific term that excludes the very question you linked to. These are not the same question at all. It is possible there is no answer that is more specific, but conflating the questions doesn't help anyone involved.

Comment: @GArthurBrown There are over 125 000 questions already. ELU is supposed to be easily searchable. I've looked at 2 lists of synonyms and 'words related to' for 'gregarious' and found only the _affable / sociable / company-loving / companionable / convivial /  clubbable ..._ 'close' synonyms. OP could have done this. If someone posts a reasonable suggestion in a 'comment', this can be re-opened. But we don't need duplicated answers or 'No' or 'No, I really don't think so' (my view). Wanting company but not sociable!!??

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think the reason this is worth keeping open is that you can't immediately think of an answer for it.